# How to read contacts info from Google with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-contacts-api

I'm working with the Google's API to get the info of my contact list and after use console log

```
    function fetch(token) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=" + token.access_token + "&alt=json",
      dataType: "JSON",
      success:function(data) {

        var json = JSON.stringify(data);

        console.log(json);
      }
    });
  }
```

I'm getting this info

```
{
"version": "1.0",
"encoding": "UTF-8",
"feed": {
    "xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
    "xmlns$openSearch": "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/",
    "xmlns$batch": "http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch",
    "xmlns$gd": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005",
    "xmlns$gContact": "http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008",
    "id": {
        "$t": "sifo.contacto@gmail.com"
    },
    "updated": {
        "$t": "2016-02-22T19:33:36.064Z"
    },
    "category": [{
        "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
        "term": "http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"
    }],
    "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "$t": "Sifo Sistema Inteligente de Facturación Online's Contacts"
    },
    "link": [{
        "rel": "alternate",
        "type": "text/html",
        "href": "http://www.google.com/"
    }, {
        "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed",
        "type": "application/atom+xml",
        "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/full"
    }, {
        "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post",
        "type": "application/atom+xml",
        "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/full"
    }, {
        "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch",
        "type": "application/atom+xml",
        "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/full/batch"
    }, {
        "rel": "self",
        "type": "application/atom+xml",
        "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/full?alt=json&max-results=25"
    }, {
        "rel": "next",
        "type": "application/atom+xml",
        "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/full?alt=json&start-index=26&max-results=25"
    }],
    "author": [{
        "name": {
            "$t": "Sifo Sistema Inteligente de Facturación Online"
        },
        "email": {
            "$t": "sifo.contacto@gmail.com"
        }
    }],
    "generator": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "uri": "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds",
        "$t": "Contacts"
    },
    "openSearch$totalResults": {
        "$t": "704"
    },
    "openSearch$startIndex": {
        "$t": "1"
    },
    "openSearch$itemsPerPage": {
        "$t": "25"
    },
    "entry": [{
                "id": {
                    "$t": "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/base/1600788a7596f9"
                },
                "updated": {
                    "$t": "2015-10-08T19:48:21.315Z"
                },
                "category": [{
                    "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
                    "term": "http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"
                }],
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "$t": "Lic. Jose Lugo"
                },
                "link": [{
                    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo",
                    "type": "image/*",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/1600788a7596f9/1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg"
                }, {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "type": "application/atom+xml",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/full/1600788a7596f9"
                }, {
                    "rel": "edit",
                    "type": "application/atom+xml",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/full/1600788a7596f9/1444333701315001"
                }],
                "gd$email": [{
                    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other",
                    "address": "jose.lugo@mecrg.com",
                    "primary": "true"
                }]
            }, {
                "id": {
                    "$t": "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/base/243862896da102"
                },
                "updated": {
                    "$t": "2016-02-11T22:58:30.580Z"
                },
                "category": [{
                    "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
                    "term": "http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"
                }],
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "$t": ""
                },
                "link": [{
                    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo",
                    "type": "image/*",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/243862896da102/qPx9RZ6Tppge180vMVnHUw"
                }, {
                    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo",
                    "type": "image/*",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/243862896da102"
                }, {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "type": "application/atom+xml",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/full/243862896da102"
                }, {
                    "rel": "edit",
                    "type": "application/atom+xml",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/full/243862896da102/1455231510580001"
                }],
                "gd$email": [{
                    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other",
                    "address": "sharai.alvarez@gmail.com",
                    "primary": "true"
                }]
            }, {
                "id": {
                    "$t": "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/base/406bac09eee821"
                },
                "updated": {
                    "$t": "2016-02-11T16:26:46.318Z"
                },
                "category": [{
                    "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
                    "term": "http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"
                }],
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "$t": ""
                },
                "link": [{
                    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo",
                    "type": "image/*",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/406bac09eee821/1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg"
                }, {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "type": "application/atom+xml",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/full/406bac09eee821"
                }, {
                    "rel": "edit",
                    "type": "application/atom+xml",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/full/406bac09eee821/1455208006318001"
                }],
                "gd$email": [{
                    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other",
                    "address": "rosyalonso3@hotmail.com",
                    "primary": "true"
                }]
            }, {
                "id": {
                    "$t": "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/base/48a21c08062798"
                },
                "updated": {
                    "$t": "2016-02-18T21:08:19.835Z"
                },
                "category": [{
                    "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
                    "term": "http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"
                }],
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "$t": ""
                },
                "link": [{
                    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo",
                    "type": "image/*",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/48a21c08062798/1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg"
                }, {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "type": "application/atom+xml",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/full/48a21c08062798"
                }, {
                    "rel": "edit",
                    "type": "application/atom+xml",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/full/48a21c08062798/1455829699835001"
                }],
                "gd$email": [{
                    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other",
                    "address": "joseluisgr15@yahoo.com",
                    "primary": "true"
                }]
            }, {
                "id": {
                    "$t": "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/base/596ac60cfe288f"
                },
                "updated": {
                    "$t": "2015-06-10T21:01:08.157Z"
                },
                "category": [{
                    "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
                    "term": "http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"
                }],
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "$t": "FLORA EXOTICA DE CHIAPAS"
                },
                "link": [{
                    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo",
                    "type": "image/*",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/596ac60cfe288f/1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg"
                }, {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "type": "application/atom+xml",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/full/596ac60cfe288f"
                }, {
                    "rel": "edit",
                    "type": "application/atom+xml",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/full/596ac60cfe288f/1433970068157001"
                }],
                "gd$email": [{
                    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other",
                    "address": "tropiflores@hotmail.com",
                    "primary": "true"
                }]
            }, {
                "id": {
                    "$t": "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/base/69c8d608c00f66"
                },
                "updated": {
                    "$t": "2016-01-07T17:00:01.946Z"
                },
                "category": [{
                    "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
                    "term": "http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"
                }],
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "$t": ""
                },
                "link": [{
                    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo",
                    "type": "image/*",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/69c8d608c00f66/bc1NAkUY9UZ5B9Ih8I16dw"
                }, {
                    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo",
                    "type": "image/*",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/69c8d608c00f66"
                }, {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "type": "application/atom+xml",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/full/69c8d608c00f66"
                }, {
                    "rel": "edit",
                    "type": "application/atom+xml",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/full/69c8d608c00f66/1452186001946000"
                }],
                "gd$email": [{
                    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other",
                    "address": "Omarpuribe@gmail.com",
                    "primary": "true"
                }]
            }, {
                "id": {
                    "$t": "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/base/8640870e6f72d7"
                },
                "updated": {
                    "$t": "2016-01-20T15:54:41.842Z"
                },
                "category": [{
                    "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
                    "term": "http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"
                }],
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "$t": ""
                },
                "link": [{
                    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo",
                    "type": "image/*",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/8640870e6f72d7/1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg"
                }, {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "type": "application/atom+xml",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/full/8640870e6f72d7"
                }, {
                    "rel": "edit",
                    "type": "application/atom+xml",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/full/8640870e6f72d7/1453305281842002"
                }],
                "gd$email": [{
                    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other",
                    "address": "aguixcor@gmail.com",
                    "primary": "true"
                }]
            }, {
                "id": {
                    "$t": "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/base/adb5708dff4555"
                },
                "updated": {
                    "$t": "2016-01-07T20:46:02.243Z"
                },
                "category": [{
                    "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
                    "term": "http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"
                }],
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "$t": ""
                },
                "link": [{
                    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo",
                    "type": "image/*",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/adb5708dff4555/1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg"
                }, {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "type": "application/atom+xml",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/full/adb5708dff4555"
                }, {
                    "rel": "edit",
                    "type": "application/atom+xml",
                    "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/full/adb5708dff4555/1452199562243000"
                }],
                "gd$email": [{
                    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other",
                    "address": "Ponyjr12@hotmail.com",
                    "primary": "true"
                }]
            }, {
                "id": {
                    "$t": "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sifo.contacto%40gmail.com/base/e5831f8fe0aeb2"
                },
                "updated": {
                    "$t": "2016-02-11T18:22:13.253Z"
                },
                "category": [{
                    "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
                    "term": "http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"
                }],
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "$t": ""
                },
                "link": [{
                            "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo",
                            "type": "image/*",
                            "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/sifo.c
```

and I would like to read the value of "address" to get the email address but I have no idea how, I tried with `$.each` but the value was "undefined" everytime, what should do I to reach the email?

Comment: Looks like you would need to loop over the feed.entry node. What were you trying to loop over initially with your $.each?

Comment: @Chizzle I was trying with entry.gd$email but obviously I'm wrong

Comment: @HailHydra : Have you tried `json.author.feed.entry[i].gd$email.address` ? Also could you post the complete json in your question, the current one is incomplete and hence cannot be used to test code.

Comment: @stark  I tried but it didn't work, but the answer of Bradley Gore worked, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what exactly were you trying to call $.each on?  On the entire `data` object, or some property?

If you just want to get the list of email addresses, you can use a `map` function to iterate over the `data.feed.entry` array and pull out the nested `gd$email[0].address` value like this:

```
var emailAddresses = data.feed.entry.map(function(entry) {
    //take the first gd$email item the entry has
    var gdEmail = entry['gd$email'][0];
    //this assumes all entries will have a gd$email, 
    //  you may want to implement a null check
    return gdEmail.address;
});
```

Comment: This works! thank you, but I don't understand 100% the part of  `var gdEmail = entry['gd$email'][0]; ` not that line but the part from the json data

Comment: @HailHydra `gd$email` property is an array, indicated in the json by the square brackets surrounding the object(s) contained `"gd$email": [ .... ]` - even if it only contains 1 item.  So, to get the first item, you have to access it via index.  If you're asking why I put square braces around 'gd$email', it's just another way to access properties in JS - some properties actually have to be accessed that way (i.e. if the property name starts with a number like '1value').  You don't have to use that notation, you could just to `var gdEmail = entry.gd$email[0];`

Comment: I got it, thank you for your time to explain it to me :)